# Car Battery charging circuit

Tags: charger

[image]
The above sketch is for  an actual battery charger. At three locations the designer has run a direct line from one transistor collector to a transistor base with no other biasing, how do you evaluate what happens in these direct lines?

Comment: Please ask a specific question. Did you design this yourself? Thanks

Comment: Please delete your comment and edit your question, the edit button is at the bottom of the question and append the info in the comment.

Comment: Defined voltage? It will be clamped between ground and 0.7 V.

Comment: Are you saying it can wander over that voltage? Or it depends on what P4 puts out? And is the 0.7 volts the minimum forward voltage over N1?

Comment: winny, could you elaborate more on your answer since it appears you know the answer to my question. I measure 0.25 volts where you say it will be between ground and 0.7 volts?

Comment: Please put @ in front of the username or the user will not be notified, like now. Makes sense, 0.25 is between 0 and 0.7. Draw the schematic into LTspice and you can poke every node for voltage and current to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting a collector to a base directly is not unusual so I'm not exactly sure where you're going wrong. But here's how I'd evaluate one of those connections - the thought process might help you get on track.

Consider P4 and N2 and denote the positive power rail by V+. The base of P4 is controlled by an adjustable reference, so imagine it can range from 0V to V+. At V+, P4 will be squeezed off, inhibiting current to N2 and turning it off. As the base of P4 falls from V+, P4 will start to turn on, which will start to drive N2's base, which will start to turn it on.

So I'd expect this subcircuit to control the voltage at the collector of N2 between V+ and 0, as the reference voltage at the base of P4 is adjusted between V+ and V+ - 0.7.

A quick simulation confirms this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no OVP, UVP OTP that is obvious.

Debug demands you know how to use a DMM with diode test, voltage measurements and use Ohm's Law.

You may use a large cap to substitute for  a battery for initial debug.